# Can we say $C_G(x)=C_G(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G,.)$ be a group with $e$ as an identity element. If $x\in G$ and $C_G(x)=\left\{g \in G: gx=xg\right\}$ and $|x|=5$. In the process of proving $C_G(x)=C_G(x^3)$, i proved $C_G(x)=C_G(x^2)$ as follows:

Let $g \in C_G(x)$

So $gx=xg$

Now $gx^2=g(xx)=(gx)x=(xg)x=x(gx)=x(xg)=(xx)g=x^2g$

So all $g \in C_G(x)$ satisfies $gx^2=x^2g$

So can we conclude $$C_G(x)=C_G(x^2)$$

Comment: If $ord(x)=n$ and if $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $C_G(x^m) \subset C_G(x)$

Comment: In general, $C_G(X)=C_G(\langle X\rangle)$. If $x$ has order $5$, then $\langle x\rangle = \langle x^2\rangle$, so the result follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Here is a lemma. Let $G$ be a group, and $g \in G$. Then for any $m$,
$$
C(g) \subset C(g^m). 
$$
Proof: If $y \in C(g)$, then $yg^m = gyg^{m-1} = \ldots = g^my$, so $y \in C(g^m)$.

Now in your group, you have an element $x$ of order $5$. The lemma shows that
$$
C(x) \subset C(x^2).
$$

But $x = (x^2)^3$, so

$$
C(x^2) \subset C(x),
$$
again by the lemma.

Answer (score 2):

In general: if $x \in G$ and $o(x)=n$, then for every non-zero integer $k$ with gcd$(k,n)=1$ it holds that $C_G(x)=C_G(x^k)$.
**Proof** by Bézout's Theorem, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ exist with $ak+bn=1$. Hence $x=x^{ak+bn}=x^{ak}x^{bn}=(x^k)^a \cdot 1=(x^k)^a$, so any element centralizing $x^k$ centralizes $x$ and the reverse is obvious.